# Brackets in output make unable to use output to identify matrix element

Tags: programming, syntax

I'm trying to write a code where each matrix element swaps with a randomly selected neighbor (cardinal directions only) to redistribute the matrix. So far I've been able to replace an element with its neighbor, making the elements twins, but I want to preserve the relative amount of "-1"s to "1"s. What you see below is what I have currently, which shows how I identify the neighbors of each element, and how I randomize which one switches with it. The output of this process gives me something in the form of `{i,j}`, which means I can't use `Si[[choice]]`, because that would be effectively saying `Si[[{i,j}]]`, which isn't correct syntax.

I'm pretty new to Mathematica, so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Input:

```
Si = {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}};

Off[General::stop];

ii = 3;    
jj = 3;

For[i = 1, i <= ii, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= jj, j++,

  choices = {{i, Mod[j - 1, ii, 1]}, {Mod[i - 1, ii, 1], j}, 
    {i, Mod[j + 1, ii, 1]}, {Mod[j - 1, ii, 1], j}};(*identifies neighbors*)

  choice = choices[[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]]]; (*randomly chooses a neighbor*)

  Si[[i, j]] = choice;(****************)

  Print[choices];
  Print[choice];
  Print[Si]
  ]
 ]
```

Output:

```
{{1,3},{3,1},{1,2},{3,1}}

{3,1}

{{{3, 1}, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}

{{1,1},{3,2},{1,3},{1,2}}

{1,2}

{{{3, 1}, {1, 2}, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}},
```

etc. and so forth.

Okay, so if I replace

```
Si[[i, j]] = choice;
```

with

```
Si[[i, j]] = Extract[Si, choice];
```

I can get the output to have replaced my original element, but I still don't know how to replace the neighbor with the value of the original element then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, the main issue is how to swap 2 elements in an array. This can be done using `ReplacePart`. Consider for example

```
array = Partition[Range[10], 5]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

and suppose you want to swap the elements at positions

```
pos1 = {1, 4};
pos2 = {2, 3};
```

then you could do something like

```
ReplacePart[array, Thread[{pos1, pos2} -> Extract[array, {pos2, pos1}]]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 8, 5}, {6, 7, 4, 9, 10}}
> ```

---

As for generating the permuted matrix, instead of using `For` loops you could consider a more functional approach. You could for example do something like this:

```
Si = {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}};
ii = 3; 
jj = 3;

swap[array_, pos1_, pos2_] := 
 ReplacePart[array, 
  Thread[{pos1, pos2} -> Extract[array, {pos2, pos1}]]]

choice[{i_, j_}] := 
 RandomChoice[{{i, Mod[j - 1, ii, 1]}, {Mod[i - 1, ii, 1], j}, {i, 
    Mod[j + 1, ii, 1]}, {Mod[i - 1, ii, 1], j}}]

newArray = Fold[swap[#1, #2, choice[#2]] &, Si, 
  Tuples[{Range[ii], Range[jj]}]]
```

Here, `swap` is a function that will swap the elements in `array` at positions `pos1` and `pos2`. The function `choice` chooses an arbitrary neighbouring position of position `{i,j}`. Finally, `Fold` is used to apply `swap` to all elements of `Si` and the resulting matrix is assigned to `newarray`. If you want to save all the intermediate results, you can replace `Fold` with `FoldList`.

Comment: Thank you all so much!! @Heike had exactly what I needed. I really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I understood the code, but if I got what you wanted to do, let's see if this helps.

This could be a function that switches a couple of positions in a matrix. `Sequence@@` is what you were looking for when you wanted to index the matrix with a list with the coordinates

```
SetAttributes[switchPosTo, HoldFirst];
switchPosTo[m_, pos1_, pos2_] :=
 ({m[[Sequence @@ pos1]], m[[Sequence @@ pos2]]} = 
{m[[Sequence @@ pos2]], m[[Sequence @@ pos1]]};)
```

or (reminded by Heike's answer of the existence of `Extract`, hehe)

```
switchPosTo[m_, pos1_, 
  pos2_] := ({m[[Sequence @@ pos1]], m[[Sequence @@ pos2]]} = 
    Extract[m, {pos2, pos1}];)
```

If you don't have a particular need to make the swap in place, Heike's answer is what you need

We create a matrix to test

```
size = 4;
sampleMat = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {size, size}]
```

The position is selected randomly, the direction too. And we repeat this until we haven't gone beyond the limits of the matrix

```
While[
  pos = RandomInteger[{1, size}, 2];
  direction = 
   RandomChoice[Join[IdentityMatrix[2], -IdentityMatrix[2]]];
  ! And @@ Thread@(1 <= pos + direction <= size)];
```

Then it's just

```
switchPosTo[sampleMat , pos, pos + direction]
```

A way to avoid the `While` and be more functional and declarative could be to define a recursive function

```
getRandomPositionAndDirection[size_] := With[{
    pos = RandomInteger[{1, size}, 2],
    direction = 
     RandomChoice[Join[IdentityMatrix[2], -IdentityMatrix[2]]]},
   If[And @@ Thread@(1 <= pos + direction <= size), {pos, direction},
    getRandomPositionAndDirection[size]]];


{pos, direction}=getRandomPositionAndDirection[size];
switchPosTo[sampleMat, pos, direction]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another way to swap two elements of a matrix/tensor:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Code:

```
{mat[[i1, j1]], mat[[i2, j2]]} = {mat[[i2, j2]], mat[[i1, j1]]}
```